# Average Score of all ratings in comments

Tags: php, custom-post-type, rating, rating-system

I have a rating system in comments, for each comment user can rate 1-5 Stars.

Now, what I want is the average ratings of the comments for each post.

Here is the link to the code file related to My rating System. Current Users can rate and comment, but I want the average of all comment ratings in that post. And this is a custom Post type.

Here's the link:
http://pastebin.com/LcRyjSPK

Answer (score 0):

From glancing at your code it seems the average rating should already be available. Is there a specific problem you're running into trying to access that data...? Is it not there, incorrect, are you getting php errors?

More info please.

Comment: i am getting errors. On Line 69 there is something called average rating. Can you tell me how can i call that in a single-places.php file to display the result on custom post type called places.